# On insert: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert in to table all those rows which are not in the xml file. When there are more than row it shows me the error: **"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, = or when the subquery is used as an expression."** This is the query what I am using:

```
insert into #tmpPievVNC
    select
        a.id, 'J'
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voav') with #vc xd 
        join nol_art a on xd.id_art = a.id
    where
            not exists(select * from nol_voav nv 
        where
            (id_art=xd.id_art) and (begDate=xd.begDate) and (endDate=xd.endDate))
```

How do I insert multiple rows there?

Comment: have you tried using `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM nol_voav nv` in your subquery?

Comment: @Greg Tried, but it gives me the same error

Comment: Exists cannot be culprit here, as it is either true or false. Is nol_art a view? Perhaps your subquery is there...

Comment: Is this the only query in the batch? What is the definition of #tmpPievVNC?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the sql statement using joins to get records not available in xml file..

Following sql statement is returning all the rows from nol_voav table which are not in xml file and then inserting them in #tmpPievVNC table.

```
insert into #tmpPievVNC
    select
        nv.id, 'J'
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voav') with #vc xd 
        inner join nol_art a on xd.id_art = a.id
    right join nol_voav nv on 
            nv.id_art=xd.id_art and nv.begDate=xd.begDate and nvendDate=xd.endDate
    where xd.id_art is null
```

You can skip the `"inner join nol_art a on xd.id_art = a.id"` statement if you don't want to join with nol_art table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the query to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
insert into #tmpPievVNC
    select
        a.id, 'J'
    from
        openxml(@hDoc, '/art_kompl/nol_voav') with #vc xd 
        join nol_art a on xd.id_art = a.id LEFT JOIN nol_voav nv 
        on xd.id_art = nv.id_art   and xd.begDate = nv.begDate and 
        xd.endDate = nv.endDate
     WHERE nv.id_art IS NULL
```

This doesn't explain the subquery error, but without seeing the tables/data you're working with, it should get you what you need